# Father script and children scripts. How to load libraries with dot sourcing in a main script which recall other scripts

Tags: powershell

I have a Main script which recalls other script by start-process or invoke-expression. As Main.ps1 begins, it loads by dot sourcing 2 scripts with some functions inside. At first I was just launching other script (for example `.\script1.ps1`) but it usually executed next Main.ps1 code lines before script1.ps1 was terminated, so I can't receive correct exit code at the right time or installations messing with other running installations. So I decided to adopt start-process and invoke-expression so I'm sure that when I launch a script, Main stops until Script1 is terminated. At this point children script can't see libraries anymore so I decided to write an IF block to see if every script is launched by the user (and then load libraries) or by Main.ps1 (libraries already loaded) but I have strange results on different computers.

```
if ($global:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name -eq $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name) {
    "Librerie importate"
    #Import-Module .\Tools\WriteLog.ps1
    . .\Tools\WriteLog.ps1
    . .\Tools\Encryption.ps1
    WriteLog -Initialize -CallingScript "$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name"
}
```

This works on my pc, but it doesn't work on a virtual machine.
So I added these lines to Main.ps1 just for test:

```
"Global: $global:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name"
"Local: $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name"
$global:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
```

and that's the result:

```
"Global: System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo.MyCommand.Name
"Local: System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo.MyCommand.Name

Main.ps1
```

the IF code block on my pc works fine because it compares "Main.ps1" with "Main.ps1"
the IF code block on the virtual machines doesn't work because it compares "" with "Main.ps1".
Why?